# reading contents of a returned array?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, return

I have the following function that is returning the category name

```
function getcategories() 
{
     global $mysqli;
$sql = "select dndo_busi_cat_name from tbl_dndo_busi_cat";

if(!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)){
die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

$row = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
return ($row);
}
```

my called function is

```
$data=getcategories();
```

i have checked the return function using var_dump($data), it is returning the array but when i try to get the output using $data['categoryname']; i am not getting any thing.

Comment: and you should also post contents of `var_dump($data)`

Comment: If you could show us the contents of the array that would be great

Comment: `mysqli_result::fetch_all` returns **array** of result records not one record. So you have to use this syntax: `$data[0]['categoryname']`. Or use loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this yielded multiple rows, then you need to loop it.

And the important thing!

You selected:

```
select dndo_busi_cat_name from tbl_dndo_busi_cat               
        ^^
```

But calling index `categoryname` which doesn't really exist.

```
$data = getcategories();
foreach($data as $row) {
    echo $row['dndo_busi_cat_name'] . '<br/>';
}
```

And lastly, always turn on error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```